# Find which IP added a specific record to a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, connections, logging, troubleshooting

Let's say I have an SQL Server running on Azure and multiple applications add records to it.
The problem is that some records come from an unknown application.

Is there a nice way of finding which IP added *a specific record*?

Comment: You need to tie the record to the IP or just find the IPs that are connecting to your server without an application name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a nice way of finding which IP added a specific record?

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
    ADD IP_Address varchar(20) 
    DEFAULT cast(connectionproperty('client_net_address') as varchar(20))
```

This will record IP address of the session that inserted the record

You can quickly test how it works, using below code

```
create table #test (ID  int)

alter table #Test 
    add IP_Address varchar(20) 
    default cast(connectionproperty('client_net_address') as varchar(20)) 

insert into #Test (ID)
values (1),(2)

select * from #Test
```

[image: IP Address]

Answer (score 1):

*Unfortunately all the apps connect through a single account they have hardcoded in their connection string. So i cannot track that.*

What i did though is that i enabled [azure sql auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview?view=azuresql).
After a day passed and logs where acquired, i inspected the audit records which also show the queries (containing the data) that every IP ran against the server.

So i could pinpoint the records that i needed against the IP that added them.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add a column which uses `HOST_NAME()` as the default. This only works for inserts, not updates.

```sql
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  ADD ModifiedByHost sysname DEFAULT (HOST_NAME());
```

Note that the host name is a connection string property, and can be spoofed.